# await Docker().containers.get() and .delete() are stuck for some containers, what might be the cause?

Tags: python, docker, async-await, python-asyncio, python-docker

On one of three identical machines running Ubuntu:22.04 and Python 3.10.12 I'm encountering a strange problem with `aiodocker`: `await client.containers.get(ident)` and `await container.delete()` are stuck and never return for some (not even running) containers but not for others.

`await container.delete()` executed on a container in `exited` state will hang until it's been deleted manually using `docker rm <ident>`. Deletion runs without problems or messages and the `await` terminates.

Running `await client.containers.get(ident)` with the same ident (now deleted) won't give me an exception as with any other random identifier but will hang also (forever now, since there is nothing to delete).

It looks to me as if *certain* containers cant' be deleted via `aiodocker` and some then set internal state keeps even `containers.get(ident)` from terminating.

This behavior can only be observed on one of the three 'identical' machines. Docker version is `24.0.5` on all of them, also `aiodocker` (`0.21.0`).

What can I do to investigate the problem? Are there known issues of this kind for `aiodocker`?